# miner.start() returns null but no transactions take place

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, mining

I have created a genesis block and initialized it in the private network. Account creation is also successful. As soon as I hit miner.start() [or miner.start(1)], the following appears:

> INFO [12-20|12:49:24.958] New local node record                    seq=6 id=cfffe86baf054a73 ip=42.106.20.83 udp=11567 tcp=4321
>   INFO [12-20|12:49:33.299] Updated mining threads                   threads=4
>   INFO [12-20|12:49:33.299] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=1000000000
>   INFO [12-20|12:49:33.300] Commit new mining work                   number=1 sealhash=12a617…a2a645 uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed=729.339µs

After this, the machine stops responding altogether. It is not generating DAG and nor is it mining any ethers.

Stuck at a dead end. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Does your machine have enough resources to run geth ?

Comment: I have 4 GB of RAM and I am executing it on Ubuntu 18.04.1. Based on the material I read online, it should work fine.

Comment: take a look on the difficulty you provided within genesis file and on a time period you set up at the begining (it is an one of options when you use ```puppeth```). I set it small and after start miner produces blocks regularly each 15 seconds.